# Add multiple angular components without the wrapper tag inside the same element

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I have a component with selector app-select

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-select',
  templateUrl: './select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select.component.css'],
  providers: [ObjectUtils],    
})

  @Input() placeholder: string; 
  @Input() dataKey: string;
  @Input() inputDisabled: boolean;
  @Input() tabindex: number;
  @Input() inputId: string;
  @Input() minimal: boolean;
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() stylesObj: string;
```

the template of this component looks like:

```
<div ngbDropdown [attr.id]="inputId" [attr.tabindex]="tabindex" [class.select--disabled]="inputDisabled" [class.input-field]="true" [minimal]="minimal" [ngStyle]="stylesObj">
... inner structure of the component ...
</div>
```

as you can see the template gives the `[class.input-field]="true"` class to this element.

I have to use provided css file which has a special style defined for `.input-field:last-child`

This is the problem because angular renders the component inside the app-select wrapper, so it is always `:last-child`

What I want to be able to do is to combine multiple components with a class ".input-field"

The template of the parent component is something like:

```
  <div class="col-ul-5">
    <app-select [stylesObj]="{'width': '100%'}" [tabindex]="'1'" [options]="documentFamilyOptions" [placeholder]="'Dokument-Familie '"
      [label]="'Dokument-Familie'" [inputId]="'select-dokument-familie'"></app-select>
    <app-select [stylesObj]="{'width': '100%'}" [tabindex]="'1'" [options]="dateRangeOptions" [placeholder]="'Datumsbereich wählen'"
      [label]="'Datumsbereich'" [inputId]="'select-datumsbereich'"></app-select>
    <div class="input-field input-field--static-label" data-init="auto">
      <input type="text" id="static-label-input-1" placeholder="User Name">
      <label for="static-label-input-1">User Name</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I need angular to render 3 components (twice the app-select and once my div component) all having class "input-field" inside the same element, but I get the app-select wrappers instead which breaks the CSS :last-child hierarchy.

Comment: Use attribute selector if you don't want to have wrapper

Comment: what can I do about all the attributes and inputs which are currently specified for the root <div> element the component template?